# Is it a good practice for derive class to be singleton

Tags: c++, inheritance, singleton

I understand that singleton and inheritance don't go well together.

My question is: Is it good practice to implement a derived class as singleton.

#### Example

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}

    void Main() { Activate(); }

protected:

    virtual void Activate() = 0;
};



class Derive :
    public Base
{
public:

    static Derive& getInstance()
    {
        static Derive  instance;
        return instance;
    }

    virtual ~Derive() {}

    virtual void Activate() {}

private:

    Derive() {}
    Derive(Derive const&);              // Don't Implement.
    void operator=(Derive const&);      // Don't implement
};
```

Comment: Singeltons in general are often considered bad practice. It does however depend much on use-case. And since we don't know the use-case, or the problem you're trying to solve, then this question can't really be answered objectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: it *depends*.

Keep in mind that *inheritance* is **primarily** not about avoiding *code duplication*. It is meant as tool. You say "A extends B" when A **is-A** B. And that of course means that "rules" such as the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) should be followed.

In other words: you don't use "A extends B" because you *can* - but because your OO model/design tells you that doing this is a helpful thing to you, and resulting in a **correct** OO model of the domain you try to, well model.

Thus the question can't be answered in general - it fully depends on your context.

But having said that: my opinionated gut feeling is: not a good idea. Keep in mind that objects of derived classes could be used as "base class" objects. In other words: you use that singleton object - without knowing about this very special contract that the one object you are currently using is about. Like:

```
Base baseA = ... nonsingelton subclass of Base
Base baseA2 = ... nonsingelton subclass of Base
Base baseB = singleton instance of Derived
```

and now:

```
baseA(baseA2) maybe works
```

but something like

```
baseA(baseB)
```

does not ... or maybe leads to breaking the singleton approach?!

In other words: this could potentially complicate your whole design. Thus I would rather look into the underlying requirement and look into other ways to fulfill those.